# Carbon Black Bit9 is blocking the project execution on VS 2017, but it is working on VS 2015 on the same machine

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a strange issue with a projects that I am trying to start from Visual Studio 2017 - project's exe file is getting blocked by Bit9. And it happens only with Visual Studio 2017, and the same is working with VS 2015.
What I can see from Bit9 screen is that msvsmon.exe is trying to run MyProject.exe and it gets blocked. I guess this is some setting on visual studio side but I cannot figure out what to change. 
I looked on the internet and I checked Debug tab of the project, and `Use remote machine` was already deselected.

Comment: It is not a "strange issue" at all, these kind of enterprisey anti-malware products never deal well with an .exe file appearing from seemingly no-where.  If you can't uninstall it then ask IT staff to help you configure it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, in a meantime I have upgraded my Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.9.17(I am not sure which version I previously had, but I think it was 15.9.11), and the problem disappeared! My colleague have version 15.9.8 and he also doesn't have a problem.